# Pointer declaration C Standard

Tags: standards

Can someone explain to me the following quote from C Standard? No matter how much I try to make sense of this I can't and how is someone, even if they are experienced in C, supposed to understand this?

C 2018 6.7.6.1 1 says:

> If, in the declaration “**T D1**”, **D1** has the form
>
> ***** *type-qualifier-list*<sub>opt</sub> **D**
>
> and the type specified for *ident* in the declaration “**T D**” is
> “*derived-declarator-type-list* *T*”, then the type specified for *ident*
> is “*derived-declarator-type-list* *type-qualifier-list* pointer to *T*”.
> For each type qualifier in the list, *ident* is a so-qualified pointer.

Comment: [I think I found a human language explanation of that.](https://books.google.com/books?id=yxLISD0TAbEC&pg=PA54&lpg=PA54&dq=c11+%22pointer+declarators%22) You can specify qualifiers like "const" not just for the pointed-to value but also for the pointer itself.

Comment: Re “how is someone, even if they are experienced in C, supposed to understand this?”: You take courses in finite state machines (may be part of a discrete mathematics computer science class), then parsing theory, then compiler construction. Having to write the compiler (rudimentary college-project level compiler) gives you practice in seeing how parsing the source text is used to generate data structures that interpret it. (These classes should be required parts of a computer science degree, to ensure students understand programming language semantics even if they do not write compilers.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First consider that `T D` declares the identifier inside `D` to be of some type derived from `T`. There might be nothing added; `int foo` declares `foo` to be `int`. Or the declarator `D` might include brackets `[…]` so that it adds “array of”, or it might include parentheses so it adds “function returning”, or it might include an asterisk so it adds “pointer to”, or it may have combinations of these (including possible repetitions). The text asked about says that inserting `*` to make `T D` into `T *D` changes the declaration by inserting “pointer of” after the other derived parts and before the `T`. For example, changing `int foo(void)` to `int *foo(void)` changes the type from “function returning `int`” to “function returning pointer to `int`”.

Here is a more detailed analysis.

Ignoring the qualifiers for the moment, the clause “If, in the declaration ‘**T D1**’, **D1** has the form ***** *type-qualifier-list*<sub>opt</sub> **D**” tells us to consider a declaration with the form `T *D`.

The next clause, “and the type specified for *ident* in the declaration ‘**T D**’ is ‘*derived-declarator-type-list* *T*’,” tells us to consider what `T *D` would be without the `*`, as if it were just `T D`. Now, inside `D`, there is some identifier, called *ident*. `D` could be just `ident`, or it could an array declarator, like `ident[3]`, or a function declarator, `ident(void)`, or another pointer declarator, `*ident`, or a combination of those, including repetitions. Whatever it is, `T D` declares *ident* to be something. Let’s say it declares the type of *ident* to be “*derived-stuff* `T`”.

The final clause of that sentence, “then the type specified for *ident* is ‘*derived-declarator-type-list* *type-qualifier-list* pointer to *T*’”, tells us that if `T D` declares *ident* to be of type “*derived-stuff* `T`”, then `T *D` declares *ident* to be of type “*derived-stuff* pointer to `T`”.

Bringing back the qualifiers, the final sentence tells us any qualifiers in the indicated position (`const`, `restrict`, `volatile`, and/or `_Atomic` between the `*` and the `D`), apply to *ident*.

Comment: @MichaelMunta: See my comment on the question.

Comment: I think there may be an error in the standard here. Consider `int * const * foo;`. This declares `foo` to be a pointer to a const pointer to an `int`. But the last sentence quoted in the question says `foo` is a const-qualified pointer. It is not.

Comment: The issue I have here is the derived-declarator-type-list T. This is not defined anywhere, reading the standard gives you no way of infering what that clause means.

Comment: @MichaelMunta: “If … and the type specified for *ident* in the declaration ‘**T D**’ is ‘*derived-declarator-type-list* *T*’” is intended to define it. It is a pattern matching; there is some type, like “array of pointer to `int`”, and that phrase is intended to say *derived-declarator-type-list* is set to match that “array of pointer to”. It is a similar use to saying “If the size of the box is x inches” instead of “Let x be the size of the box in inches.” 6.7.8 3 also uses *derived-declarator-type-list* and mentions “*derived-declarator-type-list* is specified by the declarators of **D**.”

Comment: What do you mean with the analogy with the box?

Comment: @MichaelMunta: The text in the standard is like “If the type specified is *x* *t*”, except that *x* is *derived-declarator-type-list* and *t* is `T`. It is the same grammatical construction as “If the size of the box is *x* inches.” The reader is supposed to see that *x* *t* can be made to match the type by setting *x* to the part that is supplied by the declarator **D** and *t* to the part supplied by **T**.

Comment: But looking at it from the perspective as if it is only a placeholder for something coming before T can make one believe that *anything* can be there. Like, they should define what this *derived-declarator-type-list* can take a value of, right? They never do that in the standard. That being said I found something that may actually be a definition in the standard. Can you check this out, it is under no. 24. http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p24

Comment: What I want to say is if that really is the definition of a derived declarator type, does it mean that the *derived-declarator-type-list* can only be a combination of the following: "pointer to", "array of" and "function returning"?

Comment: @MichaelMunta: The *derived-declarator-type-list* includes all the information provided by declarators. The principal parts of that is just “pointer to,” “array of”, and “function returning,” but I expect it also includes optional qualifiers for the pointer, optional qualifiers for the array, an optional size for the array, an optional `static` modifier for the array size, and the optional *parameter-type-list* for the function.